# Java method in class cannot be applied to given types found no arguments

Tags: java, class, methods, arguments

any ideas ? trying to print list I fill it in by entering the data by hand and I get this error

> **"java: method getAllCourses in class DS.Info cannot be applied to given types;   required: DS.Courses   found: no arguments   reason:
> actual and formal argument lists differ in length"**

[image: 1]

```
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private ArrayList<Courses> allCourses = new ArrayList<Courses>();

    public Info(String name, String email, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void addCourses(int id,String name, int price, int start, int end) {
        addCourses(new Courses(id,name,price,start,end));
    }

    public void addCourses(Courses courses) {
        allCourses.add(courses);
    }

    public String getAllCourses(Courses courses) {
        return courses.toString();
    }
}

     case "K":
                    if (info.getAllCourses().size() == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Kursų nėra");
                    } else System.out.println("C");
            }
        }

}
```

```
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public int price;
    public int start;
    public int end;

    public Courses(){

    }

    public Courses(int id,String name, int price, int start, int end) {
        this.id=id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Name issn" + name;
        }

}
```

Comment: The method `getAllCourses(Courses courses)` requires you to pass a `Courses` object as a parameter that it will then return a String representation of. Which btw. makes very little sense. I'm pretty sure the method should rather be `public List<Courses> getAllCoursed() { return this.allCourses;}`

Comment: You seem to expect `getAllCourses` to return some sort of `List`, but it returns a `String` instead. And it expects you pass it the courses, which you don't do. It should probably accept no argument and return `allCurses` instead of converting a `Course` to a string.

Comment: Also, `Courses` should probably be called `Course` instead, since it represents a single course.

Comment: OH GOD SPIDER works with your solution thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your getAllCourses method expects a parameter of Courses object.

```
public String getAllCourses(Courses courses) {
    return courses.toString();
}
```

If I understand what you are trying to do, this method should not accept any parameter and return a list of Courses which is the ***allCourses***